# How to save each row of json file

Tags: php, json

in this functions, I'm about to save the `users.json` in `logs` directory. then save each row of the saved file in separated files: `user_1.json, user_2.json, user_3.json`.

**The Problem:** the saved file, such as `user_1.json` is empty. and i don't know what`s wrong

here is what I've done:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('logs/users.json',file_get_contents('http://webtrim.ir/json/users.json'));
$user_list = file_get_contents('logs/users.json');
$user_list = json_decode($user_list, false);
$all_users = $user_list->data[0]->users->data;

// Saving Method 

foreach ($all_users as $key => $user) {
    $user_id = $user->id;
    file_put_contents('logs/user_' . $user_id . '.json', $user);
}
```

Comment: What does the original json look like, or `$user`?

Comment: @kerbholz i've try'd it with `file_get_contents('logs/users.json')` . but all file is the same size as original file: `users.json`

Comment: @kerbholz with `$user` all files are `0 KB`

Comment: @kerbholz `print_r($user); echo "<br>";` listed all users in each line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is decode the array back into JSON before you put it into the new file

```
<?php
file_put_contents('logs/users.json',file_get_contents('http://webtrim.ir/json/users.json'));
$user_list = file_get_contents('logs/users.json');
$user_list = json_decode($user_list, false);
$all_users = $user_list->data[0]->users->data;

// Saving Method 

foreach ($all_users as $key => $user) {
    file_put_contents('logs/user_' . $user->id . '.json', json_encode($user));
    //             changed code      ^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Amended to use the users `id` and not the occurance of the array ( Sorry, my fault).

That will get you into another problem as the `id` of 3 is used for Sara and Jack, but it would appear to be unique if you were to use `id` and `cat` but you will have to check that with the file producer or a larger dataset

So you could try

```
<?php
file_put_contents('logs/users.json',file_get_contents('http://webtrim.ir/json/users.json'));
$user_list = file_get_contents('logs/users.json');
$user_list = json_decode($user_list, false);
$all_users = $user_list->data[0]->users->data;

// Saving Method 

foreach ($all_users as $user) {
    $uniq = $user->id . $user->cat;
    file_put_contents("logs/user_$uniq.json", json_encode($user));
}
```

Comment: thats what I'm looking for.
how can i use `$user->id` as the file name: `"user_'. $user_id. '.json"`

Comment: Amended my answer for your comment

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should use `$key` instead of `$user->id` because user IDs are not unique and you are rewriting some files and losing info, for instance, Jack and Sara have both id=3, so you're rewriting Jack's info with Sara's.

The actual problem of why your json files are empty is because you forgot to `json_encode` the info before saving it to disk again.

Change:

```
file_put_contents('logs/user_' . $user_id . '.json', $user);
```

with:

```
file_put_contents('logs/user_' . $key . '.json', json_encode($user));
```

Comment: thanks for your good information, i have to admit the similar id was my bad. but your information is useful ♥